# Snowflake Terraform local development using browser authentication?

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

does anyone have a solution for Snowflake-Terraform developers to authenticate using single-sign-on browser-based authentication when running commands like `terraform init` or `terraform plan`?

We're using Github Actions for deployment and don't want to give out the credentials of a Snowflake user service account just for development.  I'm hoping there is something in Terraform that similar to dbt's [externalbrowser](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/snowflake-setup#sso-authentication) configuration.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Snowflake provider for Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest) does support browser auth. Set the optional parameter [browser_auth](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs#browser_auth) equal to true in your provider configuration.

```
provider "snowflake" {
    account      = "<Your Snowflake account>"
    region       = "<Your account region>"
    username     = "<Your username>"
    role         = "<Your role>"
    browser_auth = true
}
```